# finite padic number uniqueness

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

suppose $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}a_ip^i=0$ where $a_i\in \{0,1,-1,\dots,(p-1),-(p-1)\}$ and $p\geq 2, p\in N$, how to prove that $a_0=a_1=\dots=a_n=0$?

Comment: Note that the right side is a multiple of $p$, and so are all the terms of the left side, except possibly for the $i=0$ term.  What can you conclude about $a_0$?

Comment: $a_0$ has to be $0$ otherwise we can not get $0$ on the right of the equation.

Comment: then can we make simple induction for getting the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that $p|0$, so $\displaystyle p|\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ip^i$. But $$ \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ip^i=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ip^i +a_0=p\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ip^{i-1}+a_0$$ and $$p|p\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ip^{i-1}$$
so you must have $$p|a_0$$.

So:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ip^i=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ip^i=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_{i+i}p^{i+1}=p\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_{i+i}p^{i}$$

Now you can divide sum by $p$ and do the same with $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_{i+i}p^i$. Formally you can use induction with respect to $n$.

Comment: why $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ip^i=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_{i+i}p^i$?

Comment: I'm sorry, typo, I corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $x = \sum_{i=0}^n \max(0,a_i) p^i = - \sum_{i=0}^n \min(0,a_i) p^i$.
The base-$p$ expansion of $x$ is ...